# Overlay video with alpha using FFmpeg on macOS Catalina... problems

Tags: ffmpeg, macos-catalina

In previous versions of macOS (10.14 Mojave and older) I used FFmpeg to overlay a video with alpha on top of another video with much success. Now when updated to macOS Catalina the same FFmpeg commands suddenly doesn't work. It just produces black where the transparency should have been according to the alpha channel. The video I overlay on top is a ProRes 4444 file (which includes an alpha channel) and it no longer works as expected.

I have tried several versions of FFmpeg from the nightly builds to the latest stable one (version 4.2.1) to no avail. Nothing works :-(

The simplest form of the command I have been using looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i skiing.mp4 -i subtitles.ap4h -filter_complex overlay subtitled.m4v
```

Doesn't work. But if I replace the *subtitles.ap4h* file with a simple .png image with alpha, it works?

I have also been experimenting with the blend filter, but I really don't understand the gist of it yet.

Can someone please shed some light on this. Have anyone else out there seen this problem.

Do you have any suggestions on how to use the **blend** filter instead of the **overlay** filter to accomplish the same task?

You can find the sample files I used in my dropbox...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z3grpsbejb1na0/skiing.mp4?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8c79lg07rbuqyhn/subtitles.ap4h?dl=0

Really looking forward to someone help me solve this mystery.

Best regards / Jörgen

Comment: I don't see any alpha in `subtitles.ap4h`. According to the log output from your command the pixel format is yuv444p12le where I would expect yuv**a**444p12le or similar. If the ultimate goal is to add subtitles, why not use a typical subtitles format such as ASS or SRT?

Comment: So you are saying that there’s no alpha in the subtitles.ap4h file? Maybe that’s the problem? I also tried with a HEVC file with alpha that I can confirm has alpha using Safari. Same problem. But maybe FFmpeg doesn’t handle HEVC with alpha yet?

Comment: `subtitles.ap4h` is ProRes. There appears to be no alpha in it. The FFmpeg ProRes decoder can handle yuva*, so verify that you are outputting alpha from whatever made `subtitles.ap4h`. No alpha support in HEVC decoding yet: [Support for HEVC with Alpha](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7965). Why not use ASS/SRT?

Comment: Yes! Finally got it to work thanks to your input! I was exporting subtitles.ap4h using AVFoundation and AVAssetWriter. I noticed that the exported file didn't have an alpha channel as you correctly stated. I changed the pixel format of my CVPixelBuffers written from kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA to kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB... and Boom! The exported ProRes file had alpha just like in macOS Mojave! Many thx for helping me out with this :-)

Comment: As a reference here is the working ProRes file with alpha produced by AVFoundation... https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcv6z82im7y1cej/subtitles_alpha.ap4h?dl=0

Comment: Now the pixel format is **yuva444p10le**

Comment: Since you found a solution to the question you can add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the answer to the problem was that I didn’t really export a ProRes movie with an alpha channel as I thought. When I did so the “mystery” was solved. Thank you for your time!